# how to viewAll the docs of an index using rest in elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

while creating a rest which function can i use to view all the documents in an index,
like for prepareGet takes 3 arguments (indexName, type, id) to view the document, i need to know a function which takes only one argument as indexName and displays all the data  in that particular index

Comment: How many documents are we talking?

Comment: all the documents present in index

Comment: In absolute terms, can you provide a count? is it 100, 1000, 10000, 1M, ...?

Comment: 100-150, need for my local repository

Answer (score 2):

If your index only contains a few documents (100-150), then you can get all of them in a single search using the `_search` endpoint with a `size` parameter that is bigger than the number of your documents:

```
GET your-index/_search?size=1000
```

Using the Java HighLevel REST client, you can do it like this:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("your-index"); 
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()); 
sourceBuilder.from(0); 
sourceBuilder.size(1000); 
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder); 
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: i need the same result using a rest api, how can i get that.?

Comment: This is the REST API call. Do you mean the Java HighLevel REST client?